# Filter JSON object array on multiple values or arguments javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, filter, attributes

```
users = [
  {
    "username": "Alice",
    "firstName": "Alice-U",
    "lastName": "Wonderland"
  },
  {
    "username": "bob",
    "firstName": "Bob-u",
    "lastName": "Builder",
  },
  {
    "username": "charly",
    "firstName": "Charly-u",
    "lastName": "Brown",
  }
]
```

I want to be able to filter this array on multiple values like:

Search Criteria: `{ "username" : "Alice" }` should return:

```
{
    "username": "Alice",
    "firstName": "Alice-U",
    "lastName": "Wonderland"
}
```

Similary for: `{ "username" : "charly", "firstName": "Charly-u" }` should return :

```
{
    "username": "charly",
    "firstName": "Charly-u",
    "lastName": "Brown",
}
```

with exact string matching using javaScript or jQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write it in the following way. If you want to do exact search write a search function like this:

```
function search(term) {
  return users.filter(({username, firstName, lastName}) => {
    return username.toLowerCase() === term.toLowerCase() ||
          firstName.toLowerCase() === term.toLowerCase() ||
          lastName.toLowerCase() === term.toLowerCase()
  })
}
```

Instead of comparing each key one can iterate all object properties using `object.keys`.

If you want to match each anything use following function

```
function search(term) {
  return users.filter(({username, firstName, lastName}) => {
    return username.toLowerCase().indexOf(term.toLowerCase()) > -1 ||
           firstName.toLowerCase().indexOf(term.toLowerCase()) > -1 ||
           lastName.toLowerCase().indexOf(term.toLowerCase()) > -1
   })
}
```

This will even match `searchTerm` anywhere. Like if you use this as `search('al')`. It will return the first object, whereas the first function will need exact string like `search('alice')` to work.

```js
const users = [{
    "username": "Alice",
    "firstName": "Alice-U",
    "lastName": "Wonderland"
  },
  {
    "username": "bob",
    "firstName": "Bob-u",
    "lastName": "Builder",
  },
  {
    "username": "charly",
    "firstName": "Charly-u",
    "lastName": "Brown",
  }
]

function searchFull(term) {
  return users.filter(({
    username,
    firstName,
    lastName
  }) => {
    return username.toLowerCase() === term.toLowerCase() ||
      firstName.toLowerCase() === term.toLowerCase() ||
      lastName.toLowerCase() === term.toLowerCase()

  })

}


function search(term) {
  return users.filter(({
    username,
    firstName,
    lastName
  }) => {
    return username.toLowerCase().indexOf(term.toLowerCase()) > -1 ||
      firstName.toLowerCase().indexOf(term.toLowerCase()) > -1 ||
      lastName.toLowerCase().indexOf(term.toLowerCase()) > -1

  })

}

console.log(searchFull('alice'))
console.log(search('al'))
```

Answer (score 5):

You can employ `.every` to check that each of the criteria keys matches:

```js
function filterBy(list, criteria) {
  return list.filter(candidate =>
    Object.keys(criteria).every(key =>
      candidate[key] == criteria[key]
    )
  );
}

let users = [
  { "username": "Alice", "firstName": "Alice-U", "lastName": "Wonderland" },
  { "username": "bob", "firstName": "Bob-u", "lastName": "Builder" },
  { "username": "charly", "firstName": "Charly-u", "lastName": "Brown" }
];

console.log(filterBy(users, { "username" : "Alice" }));
console.log(filterBy(users, { "username" : "charly", "firstName": "Charly-u" }));
```

Comment: thumbs up for a generic solution with `criteria` :)

Answer (score 1):

Why not [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)? to filter only the element that has `username="Alice"`. By the way you can add multiple object keys inside your filter's arrow function while filtering array of object. For example:

```
user.username ==='Charly' && firstName==='Charly-u'
```

```js
users = [{
    "username": "Alice",
    "firstName": "Alice-U",
    "lastName": "Wonderland"
  },
  {
    "username": "bob",
    "firstName": "Bob-u",
    "lastName": "Builder",
  },
  {
    "username": "charly",
    "firstName": "Charly-u",
    "lastName": "Brown",
  }
];

result = users.filter(user => user.username ==='Alice');

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

can’t it be just a function with for loop?
    //call
    this.filterIt( ‘username’ , ‘Alice’, users);

```
//function
Function filterIt (key, value, arr){
result = [];
for ( a in arr){
   if (a[key] == value) result.push(a);
}
return result;
}
```